# Can I omit the fieldset label in a confirmation email?

Tags: webforms

Using the Webform module 8.x, I would like that the email sent with the webform_submission_values doesn't include the fieldset labels.

How can I achieve this?
Alternatively, is there a way to not send the Page label in the email?

In my case, page label and fieldset label are the same. The confirmation email shows the same value twice.

Comment: Why not just use the option to customise the content and add tags for the fields?

Comment: Reason is I have a few dozen fields and did not want to add a line for each field. Was trying to just use the [webform:submission:values] tag but somehow not have either the page label or the fieldset label be sent with the email.

Comment: I think the submission is themable as webform-submission.html.twig. I'd suggest looking into that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out the hook preprocess_webform_confirmation.
There you can strip out what you want from the confirmation message.

There is a quite good example over here: https://agileadam.com/2020/04/overriding-a-webform-confirmation-message-in-drupal-8/